# Insert records using ExecuteNonQuery, showing exception that invalid column name

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I want to insert records into a table using `ExecuteNonQuery`, for that I have written:

```
customUtility.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into furniture_ProductAccessories(Product_id, Accessories_id, SkuNo, Description1, Price, Discount) values(" + prodid + "," + strAcc + "," + txtSKUNo.Text + "," + txtAccDesc.Text + "," + txtAccPrices.Text + "," + txtAccDiscount.Text + ")");
```

& following is `ExecuteNonQuery` function:

```
    public static bool ExecuteNonQuery(string SQL)
    {
        bool retVal = false;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con, trans);
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trans.Commit();
                retVal = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(SQL + "<br>" + ex.Message);
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                con.Close();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

But it's showing exception that *invalid column name to `Description1`* and even it's value which coming from `txtAccDesc.Text`. I have tried by removing `Description1` column, other records are getting inserted successfully.

Comment: do u have a column with name "Description1" in your table ?. if exists, check whether its matching with the column name. if it contains some spaces in you column name try put square brackets, like [Description1].

Comment: You need to read up on using **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL ! Doing so opens your code up for SQL injection attacks - you don't want that to happen......

Answer (score 5):

My psychic debugging powers are telling me you're entering in the value `Description1` into the textbox `txtAccDesc`. When you concatenated the SQL string You failed to delimit the literal value.

e.g.

```
"," + txtAccDesc.Text + "," +
```

Should be

```
", '" + txtAccDesc.Text + "', " +
```

However this is a bad solution because it **opens you up to SQL injection attacks** (not to mention you'd need to deal with quotes and commas in your literals) you should use [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) instead.

e.g. (Warning written in notepad and may not compile)

```
string SQL = "insert into furniture_ProductAccessories(Product_id,Accessories_id,SkuNo,Description1,Price,Discount) values(@Product_id,@Accessories_id,@SkuNo,@Description1,@Price,@Discount)"

SqlParameters[] parameters = new SQLParameters[6];
parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@Product_id", SqlDbType.Int, prodid );
parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@Accessories_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, strAcc );
parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@SkuNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, txtSKUNo);
parameters[3] = new SqlParameter("@Description1", SqlDbType.VarChar, txtAccDesc.Text);
parameters[4] = new SqlParameter("@Price", SqlDbType.Money, txtAccPrices.Text);
parameters[5] = new SqlParameter("@Discount", SqlDbType.Money, txtAccDiscount.Text);

customUtility.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, paramters)

public static bool ExecuteNonQuery(string SQL, SqlParameters[] parameters)
{
    bool retVal = false;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, con, trans);
        cmd.parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
            retVal = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(SQL + "<br>" + ex.Message);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        // finally
        //{
            //Always call Close when done reading.
            //con.Close(); Using already does this, so need for this
        //}
        return retVal;
    }
}
```